# echo "no results found" if no matches found

Tags: php

I am using the following code to return data that contains "http://" - code is working fine and i get the data I need.

WORKING CODE

```
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
        echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>";
    }
}
```

However, I want it to also return a message if no matches are found. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

NOT WORKING CODE

```
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value) === false) {
        echo 'no matches found';
    } elseif (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
    echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>";
    }
}
```

Also, tried this but its not good as i get a repeat of "no matches found" for every iteration.

```
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
        echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>";
    } else { 
      echo "no matches found";

    }
}
```

I need it to check once and if no "http://" is found in the array then return only once "no matches found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `boolean` variable should be a good approach in this case.

As soon as we have a match, we will set the boolean value to `true`.
Otherwise, it would have its initial value - `false`.

After the loop, we should check the variable's value and in case it has been remained `false` we should print the "no matches found" message.

```
$matches = false;
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
        echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>";
        $matches = true;
    }
} 

if(!$matches){
 echo "no matches found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable which makes sure you only output once `no matches`, like this:

```
$error = FALSE;
foreach($all_urls as $index => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/http:/', $value)) {
        echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>";
    } else { 
      if(!$error) {
        echo "no matches found";
        $error = TRUE;
      }

    }
}
```